# How to properly call a method on a Vue component

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I'm quite new to using Vue2. I'm using the Vue CLI so I just follow the structure of what's generated from it.

What I'm trying to do is submit form data. But I keep getting this warning and error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "onSubmit" is not defined on the instance but 
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in 
>   the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

and

> Uncaught TypeError: _vm.onSubmit is not a function

Here's the relevant code from my `.vue` file:

```
<script>
import { contact } from './my/exports';

export default {
  name: 'Contact',
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        name: ''
      }
    }
  },
  method: {
    onSubmit: function () {
      console.log('My Logic Here')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text here..." v-model="form.name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

I can't seem to call the method from my instance. To me, it sounds like I need to make use of the lifecycle hooks? Or am I wrong? I can't find any examples of calling methods from a button click. Most of them are usually used on initialization of an instance.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: `methods` not `method`

Comment: Omg. You're right. Stupid me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the correct component property for [Method Handlers](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#methods) must be `methods` and not `method`.

However, if others have this problem and stumble upon this, I'm also going to explain a problem I just resolved in some code I was writing.

For me this was happening on a `@click=""` handler inside of some code that was using `Teleport` and a custom `Component` and I thought that was all related.

However, after many hours of debugging, I discovered that the only problem I had was that I simply misplaced a closing brace `}` character that terminated the `methods` property declaration prematurely!!

So if you encounter an event handler method `is not defined` type of problem in Vue, and all else looks right, verify that the component `methods` property is declared correctly and not terminated prematurely.